# Full text search solutions for Java?

Tags: java, full-text-search, nosql, full-text-indexing

There's a large set of entities of different kinds:

```
interface Entity {
}

interface Entity1 extends Entity {
  String field1();
  String field2();
}

interface Entity2 extends Entity {
  String field1();
  String field2();
  String field3();
}

interface Entity3 extends Entity {
  String field12();
  String field23();
  String field34();
}

Set<Entity> entities = ...
```

The task is to implement full text search for this set. By full text search I mean I just need to get entities that contain a substring I'm looking for (I **don't** need to know exact property, exact offset of where this substrig is, etc). In current implementation the `Entity` interface has a method `matches(String)`:

```
interface Entity {
  boolean matches(String text);
}
```

Each entity class implements it depending on its internals:

```
class Entity1Impl implements Entity1 {
  public String field1() {...}
  public String field2() {...}

  public boolean matches(String text) {
    return field1().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase()) ||
           field2().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase());
  }
}
```

I believe this approach is really awful (though, it works). I'm considering using Lucene to build indexes every time I have a new set. By index I mean *content -> id* mappings. The content is just a trivial "sum" of all the fields I'm considering. So, for `Entity1` the content would be concatenation of `field1()` and `field2()`. I have some doubts about the performance: building the index is often quite an expensive operation, so I'm not really sure if it helps.

Do you have any other suggestions?

To clarify the details:

1. `Set<Entity> entities = ...` is of ~10000 items.
2. `Set<Entity> entities = ...` is not read from DB, so I can't just add `where ...` condition. The data source is quite non-trivial, so I can't solve the problem on its side.
3. `Entities` should be thought of as of short articles, so some fields may be up to 10KB, while others may be ~10 bytes.
4. I need to perform this search quite often, but both the query string and original set are different every time, so it looks like I can't just build index once (because the set of entities is different every time).

Comment: It seems from your clarifications that every search has an independent set of entities to search. Is that right? If so, any indexing approach would be a waste of time. If there is some relationship between the entities from one search to the next, then you could consider some sort on incremental indexing scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such a complex Object domain, you can use lucene wrapper tool like [Compass](http://compass-project.org/) which allow quickly map you object graph to lucene index using the same approach as ORM(like hibernate)

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly consider using Lucene with SOLR. http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html